# What does WebActivator do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ef-code-first

This code was generated for me after added entity framework code-first for SQL Server CE using NuGet. They did no changes to any other file. The file `SQLCEEntityFramework.cs` was created and placed in `App_Start` folder.

Does this mean it automatically gets executed or something? The same thing happened when I added Ninject for MVC 3. No code was added to the `global.ascx` file so I have no idea if its plug and play or I have to configure something.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(StackTorrents.WebUI.App_Start.SQLCEEntityFramework), "Start")]
```

Comment: This link : ([Define an initialization order of WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12590328/1997229)) may help whom the order of execution is important for them.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx

> This new attribute allows you to have
>   code run way early in the ASP.NET
>   pipeline as an application starts up.
>   I mean way early, even before
>   Application_Start. This happens to
>   also be before code in your App_code
>   folder (assuming you have any code in
>   there) has been compiled. To use this
>   attribute, create a class library and
>   add this attribute as an assembly
>   level attribute. A common place to add
>   this would be in the AssemblyInfo.cs
>   class within the Properties folder.

Comment: The PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute from the .NET framework allows only one per assembly. Most importantly, WebActivator provides it's own implementation of the attribute that permits multiple instances of per assembly.

Comment: @Ed Chapel - does this mean that when I imported SQLCE4 from nuget and also ninject, both has a `PreApplicationStartMethod`. Only a random one will be executed?

Comment: I don't know about SQLCE4, but ninject uses WebActivator. I am certain that if you stick to the WebActivator attribute that all of the `PreApplicationStartMethod` attributes will run.

Comment: I'm glad I found this. You can not search for Stack Overflow Exceptions in google any more.

Answer (score 21):

To clarify, it gives you a way of hooking into several application start and application shutdown events WITHOUT having to change any existing code files (previously you had to edit Globals.asax.cs).

This is mostly a big deal when making packages as these events are really useful for bootstrapping Http modules and it is really difficult to write code into existing files.