# Adding dll gives following error in some projects: Could not load file or assembly [...]

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I am trying to add a DLL to my solution. I do this by a post build script, and I can see the DLL file are being added perfectly so my bin folder as epected.

The particular [DLL is the Ghostscript.net](https://github.com/mephraim/ghostscriptsharp), where I load `gsdll32.dll` to the bin folder by my post build script.

In my ASP.NET MVC 4.5 project, I get an error page with the following info:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'mypath\bin\gsdll32.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

However, I have been able to get it to work in two other websites (a Web Forms 4.5 and an another ASP.NET MVC 4.5).

Therefore my question is: how do I debug an error like this?

The problem is not as much the problem [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602912/how-to-debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-runtime-errors) (despite same title), but that there is something in my project which is problematic, and causes the DLL file to give me a `"could not load"` error.

**My web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c55a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    my connection strings
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="false" />

  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="website.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
        <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)/$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=publickey3134" />
      <connectionString value="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LetterAmazer;integrated security=true" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO DbLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You could try http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com which allows you to specify full ghostscript dll path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common reason - "file missing" as covered in linked post - does not apply according to OP.

The second reason is mismatch between process bitness (likely x64 for ASP.Net site) and interop/native libraries (likely x86/32bit based on the file name). Solution - make sure to use matching assemblies/native image for each flavor. Possibly comile managed code to just on x64 or x86 platform to force correct native binaries to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two websites inside same solution, one work, and with another one, it doesn't. Are you saying there is most likely a difference between the two websites inside my solution (ie. one run x64, other x86) ? :-)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard Since you've checked that all files are in place bitness mismatch is next thing I'd check (assuming you use IIS to host sites). The reason is bitness of process controlled outside of solution (i.e. in IIS it is how you setup your app pool) - so even if 2 sites are in the same solution one can run as x86 and another as x64 if hosted in 2 different app pools configured differently.

Comment: IIS doesn't host file. However, now I deleted every DLL file one at a time. I found out the second I deleted some "WebActivator.dll" file, it worked...

Any idea how a DLL file could have that influence? :)

Thanks a lot for your help by the wya

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard - no idea... maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812596/what-does-webactivator-do